# Get information about invitation of B2B user in Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to create an application in which I need to know whether user invited to Azure Active Directory accepted an invitation or not. I'm using microsoft graph SDK for C# to get information about users from AAD but I cannot find information about invitation status in the resulting user object. In particular, I want to get this piece of information from Azure:
[image]

Is there any way to get this info from C# using Microsoft Graph SDK or with direct graph query?

Comment: Hi Salin, may I know if the solution I provided works ? If it helps your problem, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks in advance~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems microsoft graph api(**v1.0**) for get user doesn't have the field to show if the guest accept the inviatation. I checked the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) of user properties and didn't find any property which matches "accept invitation". But I found there is a property `externalUserState` in microsoft graph api(**beta version**) which can meet your requirements. **If you don't mind the stability, you can use the beta version of microsoft graph api. If you will use this api in production environment, I suggest you to use Azure AD graph api. Please refer to the steps below**:

As a workaround, we can use Azure AD graph api instead of microsoft graph api. I found there is a property `UserState` in the response of [Azure AD graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#basic-operations-on-users--). If we want to request this Azure AD graph api, we need to add the required permissions first.
[image]
[image]

Don't forget grant admin consent and then request the access token, please note that when request the access token for Azure AD graph, we need to change the `scope` from `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` to `https://graph.windows.net/.default`.

[image]

Then use the access token to request the Azure AD graph api.

```
https://graph.windows.net/<tenant id>/users/<object id>?api-version=1.6
```

Get the response of the api and we can find there is a property `userState` in it. If the guest has accepted, this property will be "**Accepted**", if the guest hasn't accepted, this property will be "**PendingAcceptance**".

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's exactly what I needed. I don't want to use Azure AD graph api so I'm gonna use the beta microsoft graph